# locale for Switzerland (to correctly display Swiss Franc)

Tags: php, locale

I'm looking for the locale to set in PHP for Switserland, for a client that needs support for Swiss Franc.

I can't seem to find the correct locale for Switserland. Does anyone know which one I can use?

I need it in the following format like: nl_NL, en_US, en_GB

Comment: is the locale you're trying to set installed on the server ( `locale -a` ) ?

Comment: fr_CH, but indeed, check what @poelinca said.

Comment: thanks guys, I didn't know about locale -a, otherwise I would have checked. Can I mark a comment as an answer? fr_CH
fr_CH.iso88591
fr_CH.utf8

Comment: @Jorre: no, only actual answers can be marked. comments are just comments.

Comment: btw, it is called Switzerland, not Switserland ;-)

Comment: Are you sure you need to set the locale and not the character encoding?

Comment: I'm wondering why you need a special locate to deal with Swiss Franc, after all it is abbreviated SFr or CHF.

Comment: well, clients can select their currency and we'll make sure it gets shown in the correct format, sometimes that's with a . as a decimal separator, sometimes a comma. We'll append the correct symbol as well if they want

Answer (score 15, accepted):

it depends on what language your client speaks. There are multiple parts in Switzerland where different languages are used.

possible locales are :

- **de_CH** (german)
- **fr_CH** (french)
- **it_CH** (italian)

if you require the setting for currency formatting only it shouldn't really matter which one you set. but it could make a difference in date formatting if you want to display names of weekdays and months.

Comment: It might be that you need to add some character encoding information such as `de_CH.UTF-8` or `fr_CH.ISO8859-1`.

Comment: I am seeing different results for currency depending upon what I pass in. `value.toLocaleString('de-ch', {
  style: 'currency',
  'CHF',
 })`